# Java .compareToIgnoreCase String out of index works with most inputs

Tags: java

I wrote a method takes two strings and determines which is longer, to check for similarities between the string. When I run this code it works in most cases. But for the two strings inputs: "abcdef" & "zyxdmmmmm" there is an error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;

public class charCompare{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
          String s1 = input.next();


          System.out.print("Enter another word: ");
          String s2 = input.next();   


        charOffByOne(s1, s2);
        System.out.println(charOffByOne(s1, s2));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int charOffByOne(String a, String b){

        int str1Length = a.length();
        int str2Length = b.length();
        int j = 0;

        if (str1Length >= str2Length){
            for(int i = 0; i < str2Length; i++ ) {
                  if(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i)){
                    j++;        
                  }
            }
            return j;
        }else{
                for(int i = 0; i < str1Length; i++ ) {
                  if(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i)){
                    j++;        
                  }
            }
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this assignment `nameLength = b.length()` arbitrarily if you are going to use `nameLength` to set the limit for your number of iterations. You MUST choose the smaller length.

Comment: What happens if `b` is shorted then `a`?

Comment: yes, I agree. I am trying to handle it using a conditional operators. thank you

Comment: @Lizzo Your code should be robust. One way to make sure is to swap the inputs. It should work with "abcdef" & "zyxdmmmmm" and with "zyxdmmmmm" & "abcdef".

Comment: also  this will never happen,
`if (a.compareToIgnoreCase(b) < 0){  nameLength = b.length();
            } ` it will just return the difference of length but not negative or positive. so your code will never set nameLength = b.length();

Comment: do this instead, if(a.length()> b.length()) {nameLength = b.length();}

Comment: that is what I ended up doing. I gave the .compareToIgnoreCase the old college try -I to tried to subtract the difference of that method to the second parameter of the for loop. @Brooklyn99 - I haven't tested all cases but I think that is going to be the solution.

Comment: FWIW, rather that repeating the loop with the only difference being the terminating count, you can write `for (int i=0; i<str1Length && i<str2Length; i++)` or equivalently write the middle expression as `i < Math.min(str1Length, str2Length)`.

Comment: Great suggestion. It help consolidate the code.